# how i can import an excel file using php and print it in a html table

Tags: php, html, phpexcel

i try to use phpoffice/phpexcel to do this but i haven't an idea of do it...
i have this form in html

```
<body>
    <div align="center">ELENCA TABELLE PRESENTI NEL DB</div>
        <form action="index.php" method="post"
        enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Filename:
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="file" name="file" id="file">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" align="right">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="/include/js/bootstrap-contextmenu.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/include/js/bootflat.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/s/bs/pdfmake-0.1.18,dt-1.10.10,af-2.1.0,b-1.1.0,b-colvis-1.1.0,b-html5-1.1.0,b-print-1.1.0,cr-1.3.0,fc-3.2.0,fh-3.1.0,kt-2.1.0,r-2.0.0,rr-1.1.0,sc-1.4.0,se-1.1.0/datatables.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

i want use it for upload an excel file and in another file call index.php, i want do a query for show the data into this excel file that i have upload in a html table, how can i do this? thank you very much

i have just installed the package phpoffice/phpexcel with composer, i can use the libraries into this

Comment: Have you looked at the Examples and at the Documentation?

Comment: There is full and explained examples in that package. Please read.

Comment: Basically you need to do a standard file upload. Once the file has been uploaded you feed it into the PHPExcel library. If you are unable to understand or find examples that will help you to do this then maybe you are out of your depth.

Comment: i look it yes but i don't understand nothing about how to do this... you can try to show me an example of the code that i can use for do this?

Comment: @FedericoCastellani the example itself is shown in the example folder.

Comment: @Plum what is the name of the example? the folder is full of the example!

Comment: You Can Use This Library It's Very Simple  https://github.com/gneustaetter/XLSXReader

Comment: @Rome i just use a phpoffice/phpexcel library i want do this using this library

Comment: So what is your specific issue? Don't you know how to access the uploaded file in PHP? Don't you know how to load the file into PHPExcel? Don't you know how to save a PHPExcel object as HTML?

Comment: no i don't know nothing about this, this is the motivation for ask this question

Comment: Well the question as it stands is very broad.... have you read the [PHP documentation about handling file uploads](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php) which should really be the starting point for what you want to do

Comment: yeah ok i read it, but i need an example for understand it!

Comment: What about the examples provided in those docs pages?